# basic JavaScript form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm testing, getting used to forms. I'm trying to make the JavaScript check the value of the  and display a little message next to it if it's not filled in. Simple enough right?

```
    <script>
        function ValidateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["Form"]["fName"].value;

        If (x==null || x=="") { 
        document.getElementById("FN").innerHTML = "This field must be filled in"; }

        }
    </script>
<body>
        <form name="Form" onload="ValidateForm()">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="fName"> <p id="FN"></p>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="sName"> <p id="SN"></p>

        </form>

</body>
```

Unfortunately, the paragrapgs "FN" and "SN" remain empty onload. I know this isn't a practical thing here since the validation wont refresh and only runs onload when the fields are bound to be empty already but I'm going to add crap in later that I already know how to use.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: The only problem is that `If` should be `if`. Change that and it works fine, so this is just a *simple typographical error*.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/9/  ,   http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/10/  I'm afraid it's not just the if

Comment: @TurgidWizard [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/12/). Just call the function at the bottom of the script, not `onload` for the form element, as it doesn't support the `onload` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the required attribute:

```
<form name="Form">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="fName" required> <p id="FN"></p>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="sName" required> <p id="SN"></p>
</form>
```

http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-introduction-and-new-attributes/#required

Work smart, not hard ;)

Since this isn't useful...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        function ValidateForm() {
          var x = document.forms["Form"]["fName"].value;

          if (x === null || x === "") { 
            document.getElementById("FN").innerHTML = "This field must be filled in"; }
        }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="ValidateForm()">
    <form name="Form">
      First Name: <input type="text" name="fName"> <p id="FN"></p>
      Last Name: <input type="text" name="sName"> <p id="SN"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahahahaha, I appreciate the sentiment, but I'm afraid that I need to use JavaScript to meet the requirements of my EPQ. There's also an underlying problem here that'll stop me from adding other validation in later on.

Comment: Added a solution that I've tested, I moved the onload event handler to the body node and it worked for me.

Comment: So the problem was the "If" and the location of my onload!? Such a fool I am. Thanks

Comment: I tested it in firefox and opera, I'd encourage you to try it in a real browser environment and see if it differs from jsfiddle.

Comment: @TurgidWizard The reason is that `onload` is not supported for the `<form>` element.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe because you capitalized the letter "I" in if.

```
 If (x==null || x=="") {
```

should be

```
 if (x==null || x=="") {
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this mistake, a rookie mistake I often bump into. Unfortunately still no luck http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/9/

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is a simple mistake, the `If` should be `if`:

```
if (x==null || x=="") {
```

The next problem is that the `<form>` tag does not support the `onload` event, and as such the function will not run. Instead do this either when the DOM is loaded or after the `<form>`:

```
<form name="Form">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="fName"> <p id="FN"></p>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="sName"> <p id="SN"></p>
</form>
<script>ValidateForm();</script>
```